# Save a binary file to /<<external-storage>>/Android/data/<<some other package>>

Tags: java, android

A few years ago I created an app to write a binary file. I never managed to get it stored in another app's data location (`/<<external-storage>>/Android/data/<<some other app's package>>`), so the user had to do that by hand.

I created the file with

```
BufferedOutputStream bos;
try {
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath + fileName));
    bos.write(myData);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and in my manifest file I included ofcourse

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Everything worked and me and my users were satisfied. But over the years, with all the new API's, things have changed...

Some users started to complain that no files were created. I discovered the problems on at least 3 devices: a Samsung S9, a S9+ and a OnePlus 5T (with OOS).

I have tested my app on my own Pocophone F1 with Android 9 without any problems. So not all Android 9 devices have problems.

I got the stacktraces from a few users and discovered that they got a `FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)` on this line:

```
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath + fileName));
```

Two users confirmed that they gave external storage write permissions to my app.

1. So I guess that my code is not so robust any more for writing binary files to external storage.
2. And it looks like it is nowadays possible to write files to other programs external data location. If so, I would like to do that.

So what is a better (or best) way to create a binary file in `/<<external-storage>>/Android/data/<<some other program's package>>/files/`?

Comment: For devices running Android 6 or above do you ask for permission in running time?

Comment: Yes, I also ask at run time to get the permission. But I am not sure if I check the permission just before writing... Thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at that.

Comment: Since [Android Q is taking away most of external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/03/25/death-external-storage-what-now.html), you are going to need a completely different approach. For example, you could use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) to put the content wherever the user chooses.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your suggestion. I will investigate the Storage Access Framework. But you said "For example", do you know other possibilities as well?

Comment: None that will work for your very specific scenario (trying to shove a file into another app's portion of external storage). You can use `getExternalFilesDir()` and kin to put a file in your own app's portion of external storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions, but I found the bug. It was somewhere else in my program. In my manifest file I asked for the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but in the code I asked the user for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. It always worked, but maybe this was part of some security leak which they solved lately. And I will use CommonsWare suggestion in the future about the SAF.